# How to add padAngle to one edge of arc using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, donut-chart

Can anyone tell me How to add padAngle to one edge of arc using d3.js ?

I have created donut chart using d3.js. And found that there is an option to add space between arcs using .padAngle(). I achieved it. As per my requirement I need to add padding only one side of arc.

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve it ?

As per my requirement, I should add extra padding for every 3 arcs. So I am passing padding using paddingFunction(it's customized) on top of arc. But it's adding both sides.

Below is my code:

```
var data = [46.00, 67, 50.00, 10.00,30.00,40.00],
        color = ['red', 'green', 'black', 'pink','blue','orange'],
        grpStrk = [0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5],           
        width = '272',
        height = '272',
        radius = height/2 - 11;



/* function to render donut chart as per values and colors */   
function renderSavingsDonutChart(data, color, grpStrk) {
    try {
        d3
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }

    /* function to return padding for chart arc based on flag to differenciate groups */
    var paddingFunction = function(d,i) {           
        return grpStrk[i];
    };
    var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius-20).outerRadius(radius);
    var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null);
    if(isMobile()){         
        width = 257;
        height = 257;
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius-25).outerRadius(radius);
        var forVbWidth = width-4;
        var forVbHeight = height-4;
        var svg = d3.select("#results-donut-chart").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).attr("viewBox","2 2 " + forVbWidth + " " + forVbHeight).attr("preserveAspectRatio","xMidYMid").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
    }else{                  
        var svg = d3.select("#results-donut-chart").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).attr("viewBox","9 9 " + (width-19) + " " + (height-19)).attr("preserveAspectRatio","xMidYMid").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
    }
    svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .style(
        {           
            "fill": function(d, i) {                
            return color[i]; 
        }
    })
    //.attr("d", arc);
    .attr("d", arc.padAngle(paddingFunction));

    //On Resize
    var aspect = width / height,
        chart = $("#results-donut-chart svg");
    $(window).on("resize load", function() {
        var targetWidth = chart.parent().width();
        chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
        chart.attr("height", targetWidth / aspect);
    }); 
}

/*Calling savings donut on page load*/
renderSavingsDonutChart(data, color, grpStrk);
```

Comment: How do you envision this looking?  Even if you pad one side of every arc, it'll still appear the same as using `padAngle`.  For instance, [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCKJlaA7LycfI4Zr6T0A?p=preview), I've only reduced the end of the arc by `0.1 radians`...

Comment: Having `padAngle` is not exactly the same as having it in only one side. Imagine a donut chart with two arcs of 180deg, with a padding of 10°. In this case, the first arc will start at 5°, going all the way to 175°, the next one will go from 185° to 355°. Having padding at the end side, will show arcs from 0° to 175° and from 180° to 355°. This can be achieved by adding half padding and then setting `endAngle(function(d) { return d.endAngle + halfPadding; })` (`startAngle` if the padding should be on the start side).

Comment: Thanks Mark, Your answer helped me a lot. I am done with it. I achieved it by customizing engAngle method.

Comment: There still doesn't seem to be a good solution for adding a unilateral `padAngle`. All mentioned solutions don't quite achieve this: adjusting the start and end angles of the arc does not achieve a straight-like line between arcs (i.e. mimicking the behaviour of `padAngle`) as they curve each arc.

There must be a mathy solution to this by implementing the same algorithm as the padAngle from the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/main/src/arc.js).